# PostgreSQL incorrect results when searching by created_at

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(sr.id) AS total,
  COUNT(sr.id) FILTER (where (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' IS NULL) OR (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' = 'false')) AS completed,
  COUNT(sr.id) FILTER (WHERE (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' = 'true')) AS denied
FROM survey_results sr
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.id = sr.client_id
LEFT JOIN facilities f ON f.client_id = c.id
WHERE
    sr.created_at >= '2005-07-01T08:00:00+00:00' AND 
    sr.created_at <= '2005-08-02T07:59:59+00:00' AND
    4 IS NULL OR sr.client_id = 4 AND 
    NULL IS NULL OR f.id = NULL
;
```

The problem is that those created_at filters are not used. It returns also records that were created in different time. How can I fix this?

Comment: OR needs brackets I suppose

Comment: I tried that but that not solves the problem.

Comment: also `4 is null` is always false, so having such thing in same group with other ANDs make the whole group false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
WHERE (sr.created_at >= '2005-07-01T08:00:00+00:00' AND 
       sr.created_at <= '2005-08-02T07:59:59+00:00'
      ) AND
      (4 IS NULL OR sr.client_id = 4) AND 
      (NULL IS NULL OR f.id = NULL)
```

Although not necessary, I would write tis using an explicit timestamp with tz and simplify the logic to:

```
WHERE (sr.created_at >= '2005-07-01T08:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz AND 
       sr.created_at < '2005-08-02T08:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
      ) AND
      (4 IS NULL OR sr.client_id = 4) AND 
      (NULL IS NULL OR f.id = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

having multiple AND and one OR makes any of where clause work, 
 you need to group clause with brackets, smth like:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(sr.id) AS total,
  COUNT(sr.id) FILTER (where (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' IS NULL) OR (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' = 'false')) AS completed,
  COUNT(sr.id) FILTER (WHERE (raw #>> '{survey, declined}' = 'true')) AS denied
FROM survey_results sr
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.id = sr.client_id
LEFT JOIN facilities f ON f.client_id = c.id
WHERE
    (sr.created_at >= '2005-07-01T08:00:00+00:00' AND 
    sr.created_at <= '2005-08-02T07:59:59+00:00' AND
    4 IS NULL) 
    OR 
    (sr.client_id = 4 AND 
    NULL IS NULL OR f.id = NULL)
;
```

Comment: That not solves the problem, query still returns invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

remove `4 IS NULL` and `NULL IS NULL`, and use brackets :

```
 WHERE (sr.created_at >= '2005-07-01T08:00:00+00:00' AND 
    sr.created_at <= '2005-08-02T07:59:59+00:00') 
    AND
    (sr.client_id = 4 OR f.id = NULL)
```